# How can I fit a Beta regression in R?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, betareg

I'm a beginner with R, and I have a vector distributed according to Beta distribution. I would like to fit a regression using this data and two explanatory variables.
I don't know the appropriate syntax though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `betareg` package. Below is an example, with two explanatory variables `batch` and `temp`:

```
install.packages("betareg")
library(betareg)
data("GasolineYield", package = "betareg")
gy <- betareg(yield ~ batch + temp, data = GasolineYield)
summary(gy)
```

There's a paper on how it works here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/vignettes/betareg.pdf

And full documentation, including examples here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/betareg.pdf